# How to decrypt Outlook traffic in Wireshark?

Tags: ssl, wireshark, tls, decryption

I have to follow Comparitech's
[SSL Decryption Guide: How to Decrypt SSL with Wireshark](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/). 
But it is not working for Outlook - Office 365 mail traffic. 
I'm seeing traffic on port 443 only and it's SSL-encrypted.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the TLS keylog export trick only works for applications that respects the SSLKEYLOGFILE setting, such as Firefox and Chrome. If you need to inspect SSL/TLS traffic from other applications then you need to use a TLS proxy.

Our [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy) tool is a transparent proxy, which can be configured to intercept, decrypt and re-encrypt all port 443 TLS traffic. It will also generate a PCAP file containing the decrypted traffic, which you can open in Wireshark. I hope this helps!